# Rails data-date-format in "Bootstrap3 DateTimePicker" Gem

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails-3, datetimepicker

I have changed datetime picker format using data attribute like

```
<div class='input-group date controls' id='datetimepicker2' data-date-format="DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A">
```

Everything works fine but Start date showing at 5/4/2016 (after two years).

How can i resolve this problem.

Using rails3 bootstrap3-datetime-picker

```
                <div class='input-group date controls' id='datetimepicker2' data-date-format="DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A/PM">
                     <%= f.text_field :event_ends, class: "form-control",id: "event_end_date"%>

                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>

<script>
 $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
        });
 </script>
```

Comment: I hope this http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ is a good reference for it

Comment: After following that tutorial i got this error

Comment: Can you show the complete HTML content and also the script added? There might be some issue with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of js conflicts in my app. I resolved it by including all js files separately in my view.

Thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

I think  you should use:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2' data-date-format="DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A/PM">
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker();
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Sorry bro i tried that too, no use and thanks for your interest.